# Timeouts that pause while the page isn't visible

Tags: javascript, performance

I'd like to have a timer API that operates similar to setTimeout, but with the difference that the timer pauses when the page isn't active/visible.

```
setActiveTimeout(function(){ alert('hi') }, 10000);
```

In other words, if the user switches to another tab five seconds into the timer, waits an hour, then switches back, they'd get an alert five seconds *after* switching back.

The reason being, a) conserve CPU cycles, b) no "pileups" of behavior when a user returns to a page containing asynchronous periodic updates.

I suppose I could try building a library that does this sort of thing, using the new page visibility API or requestAnimationFrame() or some combination thereof, but it seems complicated, and I was hoping somebody might be aware of an easy solution, or a library that does this.

Thanks.

Comment: And just to clarify, native setTimeout() doesn't seem to behave this way. I'm definitely seeing updates pile up on my page when I switch back to it.

Comment: It does seem like various browsers slow down the timer and/or defer the callback until return, but you don't get the pausing functionality that I'm looking for. Which seems reasonable given setTimeout is such a general-purpose function.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try stopping the counter on the `blur` event, and restarting on `focus`:

```
window.onfocus = function(e) {
    // restart counter
    // I recommend setInterval
}

window.onblur = function(e) {
    // stop counter
    // with clearInterval
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this in enough places in my code that I'd definitely want to make it into a utility, so that all my timers are centrally managed. Plus I'd have to set the timeout for the *remainder* of the time, not just restart it. That's what I meant by it seeming possible, just complicated. Ideally, there would be some well-known library for this that I managed to overlook in my google searches :)

Comment: Hard to suggest an implementation without seeing your code, but why don't you use `setInterval` and increment (or decrement) a counter, instead of calculating the timeout/interval? You just can't pause js timers...

Comment: setInterval runs repeatedly, whereas I'm looking for setTimeout, which only runs once. Or more likely I'm not understanding what you're suggesting. Pausing JS timers is *exactly* what I want, incidentally ;)

Comment: I was assuming you wanted to have some kind of visual countdown also, which would require setInterval (or the callback to setTimeout calling setTimeout again). I know you want to pause the timers, but you just can't :(